# How to send silent foreground notification using Exoplayer's PlayerNotificationManager

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

I am using the latest version of Exoplayer (2.16.1). I create my foreground service notification using the code below but it comes with a notification sound. How can I prevent this sound?

```
 override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    playerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager
        .Builder(this, 9998, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(PlayerNotificationAdapter())
        .setChannelImportance(IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        .setNotificationListener(object : PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener {
            override fun onNotificationPosted(
                notificationId: Int,
                notification: Notification,
                ongoing: Boolean
            ) {
                super.onNotificationPosted(notificationId, notification, ongoing)
                if (ongoing) {
                    startForeground(notificationId, notification)
                }
            }

            override fun onNotificationCancelled(
                notificationId: Int,
                dismissedByUser: Boolean
            ) {
                super.onNotificationCancelled(notificationId, dismissedByUser)
                stopSelf()
                stopForeground(false)
            }
        })
        .setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.NotificationChannelName)
        .setChannelDescriptionResourceId(R.string.NotificationChannelDescription)
        .build()

    playerNotificationManager.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play)
    playerNotificationManager.setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
    playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(musicPlayerManager.exoPlayer)

    mediaSessionCompat = MediaSessionCompat(this, MEDIA_SESSION_TAG)
    mediaSessionCompat.isActive = true
    playerNotificationManager.setMediaSessionToken(mediaSessionCompat.sessionToken)

    mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSessionCompat)

    val timelineQueueNavigator = object : TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSessionCompat) {
        override fun getMediaDescription(
            player: Player,
            windowIndex: Int
        ): MediaDescriptionCompat {
            return MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder().build()
        }
    }
    mediaSessionConnector.setQueueNavigator(timelineQueueNavigator)
    mediaSessionConnector.setPlayer(musicPlayerManager.exoPlayer)
}
```

Please note that I want to use PlayerNotificationManager of Exoplayer to create the notification.

Answer (score 0):

you can set : playerNotificationManager.setPriority(PRIORITY_DEFAULT) to make silent notification in this case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that didn't work but I tried the following and it worked:
.setChannelImportance(IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)